# How do I compute the number of valleys in a sequence of numbers?

Tags: c, algorithm

Given a sequence of digits, a valley is defined as the region in the sequence that is surrounded (to the left and right) by higher values. The task is to find the number of valleys in the sequence.
For example,

```
{9,8,7,7,8,9} has one valley at {7,7}
{9,8,7,7,8,6,9} has two valleys at {7,7} and {6}
{7,8,9,8,7} has no valleys
```

The code I have to compute the number of valleys is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 40
int main()
{
   int input;
   int store[SIZE];
   int i = 0;
   int j;
   int valley = 0;
   int count = 0;

   printf("Enter sequence: ");
   scanf("%d", &input);
   while(input != -1)
   {
     store[i] = input;

     i++;

     scanf("%d", &input);
   }

   count = count + i;
   for(i = 1; i < count; i++)
   {
     for(j = i; j < i + 1; j++)
     {

       if((store[j-1] > store[j]) && (store[j] < store[j+1]))
       {
         valley = valley + 1;
         break;
      }
    }
  }

  printf("Number of valleys: %d", valley);

  return 0;
}
```

I am able to display the correct answer if the input is "3 2 1 2 3". However, if in between the number is equal to another and they are side by side (for example, "3 1 1 2"), the program will compute the wrong answer. 
How do I go about writing the program so that I am able to display the correct number of valleys?

Comment: For the input `9,8,7,7,8,6,9`, what about this valley `8,7,7,8,6,`?

Comment: The definition seems to imply that `4,1,3,2,4` has 3 valleys, is that right?

Comment: @n.m. Interesting thought: `4,1,3,2,4`. `1` and `2` are certainly in valleys.  The tricky part is `3`.  Locally, it is not in a valley, in fact it is a crest.  But it is in a [Big Valley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Valley) surround by `4` and `4`.  Hmmm?  Look forward to OP's reply.

Answer (score 1):

Look for slope changes from down to up.

Rather than a double nested for loop, march along looking for slope changes from down to up.  Consider any slope of 0 to be the same as the previous slope.

```
size_t Valley(const int *store, size_t count) {
  size_t valley = 0;
  int slope = -1;
  size_t i;

  // Find first down slope
  for (i = 1; i < count; i++) {
    if (store[i] < store[i - 1]) {
      break;
    }
  }

  for (; i < count; i++) {
    int newslope = (store[i] > store[i - 1]) - (store[i] < store[i - 1]);
    // Loop for slope changes
    if (newslope == -slope) {
      if (newslope > 0)
        valley++;
      slope = newslope;
    }
  }

  return valley;
}
```

Test code.

```
void Vtest(const int *store, size_t count) {
  size_t n = Valley(store, count);
  printf("%zu %zu\n", count, n);
}

void Vtests(void) {
  int a1[] = { 9, 8, 7, 7, 8, 9 };
  Vtest(a1, sizeof a1 / sizeof a1[0]);
  int a2[] = { 9, 8, 7, 7, 8, 6, 9 };
  Vtest(a2, sizeof a2 / sizeof a2[0]);
  int a3[] = { 7, 8, 9, 8, 7 };
  Vtest(a3, sizeof a3 / sizeof a3[0]);
  int a4[] = { 3, 2, 1, 2, 3 };
  Vtest(a4, sizeof a4 / sizeof a4[0]);
  int a5[] = { 8, 7, 7, 8, 6 };
  Vtest(a5, sizeof a5 / sizeof a5[0]);
}

int main(void) {
  Vtests();
  return 0;
}

Output
6 1
7 2
5 0
5 1
5 1
```

Comment: What does your code return for `3 2 1 2 3`? It is supposed to return 2

Comment: @Smac89 Code updated.  "sequence that is surrounded (to the left and right) by higher values." implies to me `3 2 1 2 3` should return 1.  Yours thoughts?

Comment: @chux - wouldn't a change from `down` to `up` (or negative to positive slope) mark a valley?

Comment: @David C. Rankin Yes.  Down to up marks a valley.  I was counting the right-hand crest.  But your thought allows for simpler code.

Comment: @chux `1` and `2 1 2`

Comment: @chux - I provided a supplement answer to your code depending on how the OP defines **valley**. Your code fits, but also fits a **saddle** where adjacent points in a valley can span more that 3 points. The supplement provided limits valley to a 3 point definition. You got the upvote :) By the way, that was an excellent use of `>` `<` to define slope.

Comment: @David C. Rankin  It depends on if left/right is the immediate neighbors or the region.  IAC, time for beauty-sleep.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
if((store[j-1] > store[j] )&&(store[j] < store[j+1]))
```

In both comparations you are using index `j`, so this program finds only valleys with length 1. Try this modification:

```
if((store[i-1] > store[i] )&&(store[j] < store[j+1]))
```

Also I am not sure, that it is right to `break;` in this situation. But it is not clear now, which answer is correct in case `3 1 2 3` - one (`1`) or two (`1` and `1 2`). From your first example we can see, that right answer is one, but it is not obvious from the definition.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you **define** valley as a **higher value to the IMMEDIATE left/right of a given point** you may need to adjust the `Valley` function provided by chux as follows:

```
size_t Valley (const int *store, size_t count) {

    ...

    i++;
    for (; i < count; i++) {
        int newslope = (store[i] > store[i - 1]) - (store[i] < store[i - 1]);
        if (newslope == -slope) {
            if (newslope > 0)
                valley++;
        }
        slope = newslope;
    }
    ...
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/valleyt
6 0
7 1
5 0
5 1
5 0
```

This is a supplement to the answer provided by chux, and the input data is as he provided in his answer. This code just limits the definition of a **valley** to being created by 3 adjacent points. (a special case of the general answer of a change from negative to positive slope with intervening equivalent points)