# Biggest pool to hold water

Tags: algorithm

Given a matrix, which values show the height of that position, find the biggest pool to hold water in the matrix. For example:

```
[0,1,0]
[1,0,1]
[0,1,0]
```

This can hold 1 in the center because values above, below, on left and right are higher than central value by one.

```
[0,2,0]
[2,0,2]
[0,2,0]
```

Can hold 2 in the center, and

```
[0,2,0]
[2,0,2]
[0,1,0]
```

Can only hold one.

Another example is a  matrix in the form of

```
[0,2,2,0]
[2,0,1,2]
[0,2,2,0]
```

in which case the biggest pool size is **3**, because the two cells `[0,1]` can store a maximum of `[2,1]` respectively so that it won't leak out through the surrounding `2` cells, and the sum of these two cells is *3*.

You can assume the matrix is an arbitrary **NxM** matrix

If the input is

```
[1,  2,  78, 39, 20]
[4,  66, 17, 8,  55]
[35, 42, 78, 31, 64]
[34, 64, 24, 55, 21]
```

the result is 61 because 17, 8, 31 can all add up to 39 without leaking.

You can subtract  `17 8 31` from 39, because all other values around that area are still bigger or equal to 39. Just image the matrix is a map, and all the number is the height of the ma. You can fill some area with water, if you find the area is lower to its surroundings.

Another way to explain it is, you can have a *pool* of **N** adjacent indexed elements in the matrix, and the biggest pool in this example is made by the adjacent numbers of `[17,8,31]`, because if you take the minimum adjacent around them, which is **39**, then `39-17`, `39-8` and `39-31` which is equal to `22+31+8 = 61` is the maximum value that can be stored in that given pool, and this is the biggest possible pool in the matrix.

**How to find the biggest pool to hold water?**

The "biggest" is defined as the biggest sum of all depths in a pool.

You are supposed to implement a function like:

```java
public int findBiggestPool(int[][] matrix)
```

The question is similar to [How do I compute the number of valleys in a sequence of numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26622669/how-do-i-compute-the-number-of-valleys-in-a-sequence-of-numbers), but this one is matrix not array

Comment: looks like it's just the minimum value of the important walls: min(a,c,b,d) from `[?,a,?][b,?,c][?,d,?]`

Comment: I assume the matrix is an arbirary NxM matrix

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compute the number of valleys in a sequence of numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26622669/how-do-i-compute-the-number-of-valleys-in-a-sequence-of-numbers)

Comment: @Smac89 it is a matrix not an array

Comment: in the last example how have you calculated the values 17 , 8 and 31 is unclear to me , can you explain ?

Comment: @ShubhangMalviya OH I GET IT, so it basically says that you can have a POOL of N adjacent indexes in the matrix, and the biggest pool here is made by the adjacent numbers of `[17,8,31]` because if you take the minimum adjacent around them which is `39`, then `39-17`, `39-8` and `39-31` which is equal to `22+31+8 = 61` is the maximum value that can be stored

Comment: I think it's basically a height map and we're looking for the biggest possible reservoir?

Comment: @Blorgbeard close but no quite. What if biggest pool leaks on some other part of important wall, and not its shortest? What if all important parts have height 0?

Comment: @AndyNewman You are right!

Comment: @Dialecticus when I commented, there were only 3 examples and they were all 3x3. Now it's clearly more complicated than that.

Comment: Smells like [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)...

Answer (score 1):

Ineffective but direct approach

**Definitions**:

- Level - a height of the water
- Overflow level - a maximum level that can be contained in a cell
- Depth - overflow level minus cell's value

**Algorithm**:

Find overflow level for every cell:

1. Create a matrix of levels filled  with maximum value
2. Set levels of border cells to their values
3. For every cell set its level to the minimum level of neighbours but no less than its value
4. Repeat 3 until stabilization

Find pools:

1. Take an unmarked cell, set pool volume to its depth
2. Recursively collect all unmarked adjacent cells of same level and positive depth, adding their depth to the volume and marking them
3. Compare pool volume to previous volume leader, remember if current is greater
4. If there are unmarked cells goto 1

Homework:

- reread cluster analysis books
- remove recursion
- merge steps
- reuse buffer

Comment: You are right. It is inefficient because you should do recursion  to find overflow level for every cell until stabilization.

Comment: @DuSun, it is not a recursion, its a loop. Recursion happens on second stage.

Answer (score 1):

mark all outside cells as "leaky"

recursively mark all cells adjacent to a leaky cell as leaky if they are as high or higher than the leaky one

After that, all cells which are unmarked are part of a viable pool - make collections of all interconnected pools (let's call these lakes).

The water level of a lake is the height of the lowest leaky cell it touches.

The total volume of the lake is the sum of all positive values of (water level - cell height)

Calculate all lake volumes and use the biggest.

This also suggests a nasty test case - make sure whatever algorithm you end up with works when the largest pool contains an island.  I can imagine a few failures there.

Comment: I've thought of an even worse test case - if one lake contains an island which in turn contains a lake (like a volcano) then I think my algorithm fails, because the volcano rim isn't leaky.  *ponder*

Comment: I think (I'd want to try it to be sure) that I can fix the volcano case with some recursion.  After getting the water height of all possible lakes, look within each lake for cells which are higher than the water, and mark them as leaky.  Then recalculate the lake they are in because it might be 2 lakes now, and they might have different water heights.  Repeat until nothing new shows up as leaky.

Comment: Final answer - rather than recursing looking for volcano lakes you can just propogate the leak-height across lakes and mark islands as leaky right from the start.  I think, though, that I've ended up with nearly the same system as Basilevs now :)